# isset($_SESSION) display $_SESSION name

Tags: php, session, if-statement

If anyone can make a better title, please edit it.

The issue I am having is being unable to show the users name in their post. Quick snip of code.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) )
{ 
$name = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else 
{
$name = $_POST['name']; 
}
```

How can I make it when the user posts it check to see if there is a session and then displays their name in their post.

Comment: Have you session_start(); on every page?

Comment: Yes. If you are not logged in you can type your own name in the input box, so what ever they enter is what $name is. I want it so when you are logged it $name because the session username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing particularly wrong with what you've done here. Does $_SESSION['username'] actually have a value?

Also, make sure when you are working with sessions that you call session_start() before saving or pulling session data.

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['username'] = 'Greg';

    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) )
    { 
    $name = $_SESSION['username'];
    }
```

Comment: Well, looks like I just spelt something wrong. Should have looked for that instead of logical reason as to why it was not working. Thanks though.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Nothing worse that a semantic error you read past over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) )
{ 
    $name = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else 
{
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $name;
}
```

Then reload the page, $_SESSION['username'] now should contain the user name

Answer (score 0):

Garrett am i right in thinking your route is create `$_SESSION['name']` first and regardless unless they have logged in if so the `$_SESSION['name']` becomes `$_SESSION['username']`

If I am right and you are creating $_SESSION['username'] on login all you need to do is check if `$_SESSION['name']` = `$_SESSION['username']` and if it does unset it example:

```
// YOUR LOGIN CODE TO CHECK ASSUME SQL QUERY OF SOME DESCRIPTION AND 'true' IS YOUR RESULT and 'false' NOT A USER
if(true) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $result;
if($_SESSION['name'] && $_SESSION['name'] == $_SESSION['username'] ){
unset($_SESSION['name'])
}
// ACTION TO GO TO PAGE
} else {
// YOUR ERROR ACTION
}
```